# Linq query to update a extracted list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to extract a list from another list of object and I want to update only the extracted list as well. Below is my code details:-

```
public class Team
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public Driver Driver { get; set; }
    public Driver Codriver { get; set; }

    private IList<Race> races;
    public virtual IEnumerable<Race> Races
    {
        get { return races; }
    }

    public virtual bool AddRace(Race newRace)
    {
        if (newRace == null) return false;
        races.Add(newRace);
        newRace.SetTeam(this);
        return true;
    }
}

public class Driver
{
    public string DriverId { get; set; }
}

public class Race
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Owner { get; set; }

    public virtual Team Team { get; protected set; }
    protected internal virtual void SetTeam(Team team){ Team = team; }
}

public void AssignValues(Team source, Team target)
{
    var races = source.Races.Where(race => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(race.Owner) && race.Owner == "Driver").ToList();
    races.ForEach(race => { race.Owner = "Codriver"; target.AddRace(race); });
}
```

The problem with AssignValues function is that the source races also get modified(Owner is changed to Codriver) but I want only the target to be updated. Can someone please help me with this.

Comment: Actually this has nothing to do with linq, which is for *querying* data (that´s what the Q in LINQ stands for), not for *modifying* a collection. Having said this you could replace your `ForEach`-statement with a normal `foreach`-loop.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Using a `foreach` instead of `ForEach` wouldn't make a difference here

Answer (score 2):

`Race` is a reference type(class), hence once you change it somewhere, it will be modified wherever it is referenced(in two different lists but both contain the same reference to `Racer`).

Maybe you want to create deep copies, for example via [copy-constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-write-a-copy-constructor):

```
public class Race
{
    public Race()
    {
    }

    public Race(Race r)
    {
        // copy constructor
        this.Id = r.Id;
        this.Owner = r.Owner;
        SetTeam(r.Team);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Now this is the easiest and most efficient way to implement your method:

```
public void AssignTargetRaces(Team source, Team target)
{
    var races = source.Races.Where(race => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(race.Owner) && race.Owner == "Driver");
    foreach (Race r in races)
        target.AddRace(new Race(r) {Owner = "Codriver"});
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to extract a new list from the source list without using new Race().

Comment: @KavyaShetty: of course, you do that already. But that doesnt create new `Race` instances, and that is what is causing your issue.

Comment: I will not be able to update the Race class because it is a legacy class being referenced in various projects.

Comment: @KavyaShetty: then dont add a copy constructor but assign the properties manually

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not related to LINQ, but to the fact that you don't understand completely how classes (i.e reference types) work. When you modify the races inside the `ForEach`, you are actually modifying the reference to the races in `source.Races`.
A quick and dirty workaround is to create copies of those objects so that the original reference remains intact:

```
public void AssignValues(Team source, Team target)
{
    var races = source.Races
        .Where(race => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(race.Owner) && race.Owner == "Driver")
        .Select(x => new Race 
        {
            Id = x.Id,
            Owner = x.Owner
        }
        .ToList();

    races.ForEach(race => 
    { 
        race.Owner = "Codriver"; 
        target.AddRace(race); 
    });
}
```

Comment: My Race class has a number of other properties in it. So creating new object and assigning is not possible

Comment: The other solution is to make `Race` a `struct`, and you most likely don't want that. How many are "a number"? 5? 50?

Comment: There are closer to 40 data members

Comment: Why not create some copy-constructor expecting an instance of your class? Of course you´d had to copy every of the 40 members, but only within your constructor, not on every call within your client-code.

Comment: Adding constructor to my classes will not be possible as my classes belong to a legacy project being referenced in various projects.

Comment: Well, there is one more common way: serialize the object into a string and de-serialize it back, but this will be much slower than just using `new Race { ... } `

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with Linq. You have to create new Race

```
 races.ForEach(race => target.AddRace(new Race { Id = race.Id, Owner = "Codriver" });
```

Comment: My Race class has a number of other properties in it. so creating new object and assigning is not possible

Comment: You can create some kind of `Clone()` method to create clone of your class. You have to create new instance one way or another. Otherwise you will modify original object.